# PowerShell Script not running when set in the task scheduler

Tags: powershell

I'm attempting to create a task via powershell to delete some files older then 6 hours, if I execute the script from powershell there are no issues, if I try to execute from task scheduler nothing happens..

Call the `Powershell.exe` in my schedulded task:

```
C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
```

Set this Parameters :

```
-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -Command -NonInteractive -File "C:\Scripts\DeleteFilesDiff3H.PS1"
```

What could be the problem of the task scheduler not launching my script?

Tried to aply some solutions provide to similar issues without success

```
$Path = "E:\MyPath"
$now = Get-Date

Get-Childitem * |
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -le $now.AddHours(-6) } |
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```

I got this messages:

```
Task Scheduler started "{38dcd44b-4210-473b-921e-3cc1442ff03b}" instance of the "\Delete Files 3H" task for user "my user".

Task Engine "S-1-5-21-159114655-2248028564-2417230598-213599:My User:Interactive:LUA[2]"  received a message from Task Scheduler service requesting to launch task "\Delete Files 3H" .

Task Scheduler launched "{38dcd44b-4210-473b-921e-3cc1442ff03b}"  instance of task "\Delete Files 3H" due to a time trigger condition.

Task Scheduler successfully completed task "\Delete Files 3H" , instance "{618e6f44-b523-4c56-ae0b-04d3552391cc}" , action "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" with return code 0.
```

Comment: Use _either_ `-Command` or `-File`, which serve distinct, mutually exclusive purposes. In your case, try removing `-Command`.

Comment: Hi mklement0 thanks for your help. Removing -Command don't change the output, even the task completion with success no file are deleted.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't make use of the defined variable `$path` so `Get-ChildItem` will never look there. Update your code to the following and check if this works for you:

```
$Path = "E:\MyPath"
$now = Get-Date

Get-Childitem -path $Path |
Where-Object { $_.LastWriteTime -le $now.AddHours(-6) } |
Remove-Item -Recurse -Force
```